# How to read a YAML file

Tags: go, yaml

I have an issue with reading a YAML file.  I think it's something in the file structure but I can't figure out what.

*YAML file:*

```
conf:
  hits:5
  time:5000000
```

*code:*

```
type conf struct {
    hits int64 `yaml:"hits"`
    time int64 `yaml:"time"`
}


func (c *conf) getConf() *conf {

    yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("conf.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("yamlFile.Get err   #%v ", err)
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unmarshal: %v", err)
    }

    return c
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta i dont get any error , just empty struct

Comment: Do you think that might be relevant to add to your question?  Also, can you paste the full code that reproduces the problem? `package main`, what files you're importing, a `main` function, etc. so that it's easy for people trying to help you to copy-paste the code and run it locally.  Think about adding information and code that makes it easy for people to help you, because you want people to help you.

Comment: As mentioned ad-nausem, anything setting fields via reflection (JSON, XML, YAML unmarshalling, etc) can only work on exported fields.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Your yaml file must be

```
hits: 5
time: 5000000
```

Your code should look like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type conf struct {
    Hits int64 `yaml:"hits"`
    Time int64 `yaml:"time"`
}

func (c *conf) getConf() *conf {

    yamlFile, err := os.ReadFile("conf.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("yamlFile.Get err   #%v ", err)
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unmarshal: %v", err)
    }

    return c
}

func main() {
    var c conf
    c.getConf()

    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

The main error was capital letter for your struct. Additionally, as of Go1.16 `ioutil` has been deprecated

> Deprecated: As of Go 1.16, the same functionality is now provided by package io or package os, and those implementations should be preferred in new code. See the specific function documentation for details.

([source](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil#:%7E:text=Deprecated%3A%20As%20of%20Go%201.16%2C%20the%20same%20functionality%20is%20now%20provided%20by%20package%20io%20or%20package%20os%2C%20and%20those%20implementations%20should%20be%20preferred%20in%20new%20code.%20See%20the%20specific%20function%20documentation%20for%20details.))

Comment: The spec on exported identifiers: http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Exported_identifiers

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I need to change the line `err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, c)` to `err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &c)` i.e. pass a pointer not a value. I have no clue why though.

Comment: It is tied down to code via type conf struct.  Won't be reusable, if config file is changed.  Is there anything that is dynamic, without having to define a struct in the code?

Comment: @joelfischerr you're absolutely right, I had to make the same change to work it fine.

Comment: @MopparthyRavindranath I think you need to use interfaces to do that, but why a config file will change several times?

Comment: @MopparthyRavindranath I think you want [something like a map of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26290943/122727), no?

Comment: @fabulias and förschter
If you are getting error on unmarshall when you dont use a reference of a pointer, the reason for this is your pointer is undefined or nil. Unmarshall requires the address in 2 cases: If its a value type or if its a nil pointer type

Comment: @förschter same in your case too, I am guessing

Answer (score 26):

#### Example

Using an upgraded **version 3** of yaml package.

An example `conf.yaml` file:

```yaml
conf:
  hits: 5
  time: 5000000
  camelCase: sometext
```

The `main.go` file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type myData struct {
    Conf struct {
        Hits      int64
        Time      int64
        CamelCase string `yaml:"camelCase"`
    }
}

func readConf(filename string) (*myData, error) {
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    c := &myData{}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(buf, c)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("in file %q: %w", filename, err)
    }

    return c, err
}

func main() {
    c, err := readConf("conf.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v", c)
}
```

Running instructions (in case it's the first time you step out of stdlib):

```bash
cat conf.yaml
go mod init example.com/whatever
go get gopkg.in/yaml.v3
cat go.sum
go run .
```

#### About The `yaml:"field"`

The [tags](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/blob/f6f7691b1fdeb513f56608cd2c32c51f8194bf51/yaml.go#L186-L216) (like `yaml:"field"`) are optional for all-lowercase yaml key identifiers. For demonstration the above example parses an extra [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) identifier which does require such a tag.

#### Corner Case: JSON+YAML

Confusingly, the useful lowercasing behavior of `yaml` package is *not* seen in the standard `json` package. Do you have a data structure which is sometimes encoded to JSON and sometimes to YAML? If so, consider specifying both JSON tags and YAML tags on literally every field. Verbose, but reduces mistakes. Example below.

```golang
type myData struct {
    Conf conf `yaml:"conf" json:"conf"`
}

type conf struct {
    Hits      int64  `yaml:"hits" json:"hits"`
    Time      int64  `yaml:"time" json:"time"`
    CamelCase string `yaml:"camelCase" json:"camelCase"`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

type someConf struct {
    AccessKeyID     string `yaml:"access_key_id"`
   //...
}

func getConf(file string, cnf interface{}) error {
   yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
   if err == nil {
      err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, cnf)
   }
   return err
}

func main() {
    cfg := &awsConf{}
    if err := getConf("conf.yml", cfg); err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
 }
```

shortest getConf ever

Answer (score 0):

Here, You can read a YAML file without having a predefined struct. Please substitute "**config.yaml**" with the desired file name. Add "fmt," "io/ioutil," and "gopkg.in/yaml.v2" to the import list.

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"

        "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    )

    func main() {
        obj := make(map[string]interface{})
    
        yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yaml")
        if err != nil {
          fmt.Printf("yamlFile.Get err #%v ", err)
        }
        err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, obj)
        if err != nil {
          fmt.Printf("Unmarshal: %v", err)
        }

        fmt.Println(obj)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated version for reading Yaml in Golang

```
file, err := os.OpenFile("config.yaml", os.O_RDONLY, 0600)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error opening/creating file: %v", err)
}
defer file.Close()

dec := yaml.NewDecoder(file)
err = dec.Decode(&Config)
if err != nil {
    err = fmt.Errorf("error loading config file %v!", err)
}else{
    pp.Print(Config)
}
```